# Need Formula assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, first of all, I have WPS office as my suite, because I cannot afford excel. The formulas are the same. I have found that out for you.

Now here is my problem. I am trying to create a combined leaderboard for survey count and quality assurance contest for my job. I have figured out the formulas for the survey scores and points and they work. Now my question is, I need to make a yes/no function and score it Yes=2 and No=0.  Can you help?

Example(If A1 is the question. Did the Agent provide self-help links, Yes/No. B1 needs to have the score.)

Comment: I gave you an UP vote to help you out on your contribution to help you with your reputation. Welcome to Superuser!

Comment: The question & answer seem to mismatch. It would help other readers if you could clarify. It isn't clear whether A1 contains the text of the question and the yes/no response goes in some unspecified place by an unspecified mechanism, or A1 contains the yes/no response. The task appears to be to convert that yes/no response to the 2/0 score.  Where is the yes/no?  Is it literal text "yes" or "no"?  The answer tests whether A1 contains the question text, and assigns the 2/0 based on whether that cell is the right question rather than the user's response to it.  Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple IF(logical_test, true, false).

In B1, make your test:
=IF(A1="Did the Agent provide self-help links", 2, 0)

That's all there is to it.

Comment: If this solution helped, please check the box to the left as a solution. This way you've declared the solution as Answered.